# Attempting to create vertical motion via kinematics in C

Tags: c

I'm attempting to print the height y as a function of time t.

EDIT:  Alright I got the code to work now, thanks to all of you! I appreciate your help!

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
    double t, g = -9.8, v = 20;
    double y;

    for(t = 0; t < 4.079; t = t + .02){
        y = (( v * t) + ( .5 * g * t * t ));
        printf("value of y: %f\n", y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("value of t: %d\n", v);` are you trying to print t or v?

Comment: `<math.h>` is the header of the math library, `libm`. So you need to add `-lm` to your linker's flags. Also, `(t * t)` works fine, and is also *much* faster than `pow` -- that one is for non-integer exponents :)

Comment: Really helps if you get some discipline about formatting your code and indent consistently and neatly. Overall, well formatted code with everything named very accurately when possible helps avoid many problems and makes troubleshooting easier for you and others. Generally putting a space around operators makes it more legible as well.

Comment: Also people usually keep the prototype definitions separate from the variable definitions. And since your variable names are just one letter I'd be really tempted to join d, v and t on one line.  `double t, v = 20, g = -9.8;`

Comment: @OlivierGrech So the idea was that for every input of t, there would be a printed output of the height y, not the velocity v, which is my fault for not being careful with my code.  However, if instead replace all t's and the v with y's, it turns into an infinitely repeating value, so there is still something wrong there.

Comment: @Quentin  Thank you!  That takes care of the error.

Comment: @clearlight Thanks, I'll keep those points in mind for later use.

Comment: Also, `y = ((v * t) + (.5 * g * ( t * t));` is outside of the for loop. Since `t` is uninitialized, it could be anything. The compiler should emit a warning about this.

Comment: @rlee827 I don't get an error back about y being outside of the loop.  The only odd thing is that everytime I run the code, the "value of y" is random relative to the past times running the code.  How would I neatly stick in the loop?

Comment: We got your code to work, but you didn't accept any answers?

Comment: @abelenky My bad.  I'll remember for any further questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
printf("value of y: %d\n", y);
```

`%d` is for printing ***integers*** (`int`).

You are trying to print a `double`.

Use `%f` to print a `double`.

---

You will have to re-calculate the value of y every time in your loop:

```
for(t = 0; t < 4.079; t = t + .02) {
    y = ((v * t) + (.5 * g * ( t * t));
    printf("value of y: %d\n", y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks abelenky! That helps a lot. I completely forgot that that would change the output.  Now instead of getting random values of y, they equal zero. 

I think this is because y is outside of the loop, as one of the comments on my post has stated, but I'm still not quite sure how to neatly stick y into the loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "y is outside the loop"? Do you mean the *declaration* of it, `double y;`, the *initialization*, `y=0`, or the *update function*, `y = v*t + g* 0.5 * t* t` (remember, C does actually use some form of order of operations- all those brackets are unnecessary)

Comment: @catalogue_number I believe what I meant was that the update function y was outside of the for loop.  I have fixed that in my current code, which now works.

Answer (score 0):

<s>**pow** becomes a reserved word/syntax once you use **math.h** and compile with the -lm flag linking that math library.  **pow** is then a function from math.h so you cannot use `pow` as a variable where you do `double pow(double t, double s);`</s>

It is best, if not just for human readability, to simply declare all your variables first. Then at most, when declaring them, assign them a value like you do for `g` and `v`.

Consider this modification to your code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>

int main ( void )
{
   const double gravity = -9.8;   /* don't be afraid to use full words */
   double v = 20;
   double t, s;
   double p;   /* changed from pow */
   double y;

   p =  pow( t, s );    /* this is t^s consider using a better variable name than the letter p */

   /* for equations like this `y=` below,                          */
   /* putting the textbook definition of it just prior and         */
   /* and explaining what you are trying to do will help immensely */
   /* later on when your program gives the wrong answer and you    */
   /* are scratching your head trying to figure out why            */
   /* and especially if it is someone else                         */


   y = (v * t) + (0.5 * gravity * pow(t, 2.0) );

   for ( t = 0; t < 4.079; t = t + .02)
   {
      printf("value of whatever: %lf\n", whatever );   /* original code had %d here, must use %lf because your variables are type double */
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: His `pow` prototype isn't smart, but the bit about `pow` becoming reserved by including a header just isn't correct. Repeated identical prototypes are fine. So if his happens to match the one in `math.h` - which it apparently does - there's no error.

Comment: how does the compiler then know whether `pow` is to be used as a function or a variable?  I believe that is why he might have been getting that error of `undefined reference to pow`, assuming he compiled with the `-lm` flag.  he already edited his original post so i guess it's mute at this point.

Comment: He got the undefined reference because the linker needed to be told to search `libm` (the `-lm` flag that others have mentioned).  The compiler knows that `double pow(double, double);` is a function prototype. He had an extra one. Repeats are allowed.